# Open link on iFrame - PHP or JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, iframe, static

Been trying for over a day so I am now going to my last resort, posting here. I have a web site with the following code

**style.css**

```
#nav li a.active {
    background: url('images/top-pages-button.png') 0 -80px;
}

#nav li ul li a:hover, #nav li ul li a.active {
    color: #6dff6d;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: url('images/pages-button.png') 0 -40px;
}
```

**index.php Page**

```
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="#" title="Top Pages" class="active">Top Pages</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="test.php" target="myframe" title="Page 1" class="active">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="test2.php" target="myframe" title="Page 2">Page 2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>

<iframe name="myframe" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none; overflow: hidden;" src="default-page.php"></iframe>
```

**test.php Page**

```
Simple PHP file calling a page with some content/info/text.
```

The above code works, there is a default page that opens when the site is loaded and when you click on a link it opens the page on the iFrame correctly. HOWEVER, I have the following needs.

- I would like to copy + paste a link to share with my friends to the
  DIRECT page opened on the iframe. So for instance I would like to
  send a link via email to
  http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?page=page1.php OR something like
  that, rather then tell them to visit mydomain.com and THEN click on
  Page 1 under Top Pages.
- Also, the site has multiple categories besides just "top pages" so I
  would like for the page to highlight where the user is, category AND
  link opened. So if I press on Page 1, for the category and for that
  link to be "active" and then when I go to Page 2 for Page 1 link to
  go back to default and Page 2 to be active and so on -based on my
  style sheet.

The entire web site has three parts. Navigation on left, Content on middle, and Chat on right side. I need the chat to be static which is why I'm trying to do this. I do want to be able to send a friend or friends a link which opens that page directly rather than the site and instruct to click on X while the category and link is marked as "active" and change like so as necessary and keep the chat div static the entire time.

Let me know if this is possible with either JQUERY of PHP please. Thank you very much!

Comment: is the iframe on the same domain or is it different domain? I dont think you can control an iframes content if its on a different domain, because of same origin policy. If its same domain you may be able to access it via js.

Comment: yeah it's all going to be on the same domain. trying to load certain links on an iframe located within the same domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `index.php`, just add some checks for `$_GET['page']` - if that's what you want to use:

```
<li><a href="page1.php" target="myframe" title="Page 1" class="<?= ($_GET['page'] == 'page1.php') ? 'active' : ''; ?>">Page 1</a></li>
<li><a href="page2.php" target="myframe" title="Page 2" class="<?= ($_GET['page'] == 'page2.php') ? 'active' : ''; ?>">Page 2</a></li>
```

Similarly, for the `iframe`:

```
<iframe name="myframe" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none; overflow: hidden;" src="<?= $_GET['page']; ?>"></iframe>
```

---

Remember to whitelist the pages allowed (otherwise the `iframe` will load anything):

```
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    if (in_array($_GET['page'], array('page1.php', 'page2.php')) === false) { // not whitelisted
        $_GET['page'] = 'default-page.php'; // revert to default
    }
}

else {
        $_GET['page'] = 'default-page.php'; // it isn't set
}
```

The above should go on the top of the page (or before `$_GET['page']` appears for the first time).